# How to create FT_Face from the CGFontRef of a system font in iOS?

Tags: ios, c, freetype

In iOS, you don't know the font file path(I mean, though you can see them at somewhere of /System, there is no API for you to get a font's path, they may be changed in future), the way to access font is by its name eg. `[UIFont fontWithName...]`, `CGFontCreateWithFontName` etc..

I need to use FreeType in my project, and I want to convert the `CGFontRef` to `FT_Face`, but as mentions above, I can't get the font's file path, so I wonder if there is some way to create `FT_Face` from `CGFontRef`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution. Read out the tables of the `CGFontRef` to form a font, and use the data for `FT_Face`. Check here: https://gist.github.com/1892760.